# ASP.Net Razor Pages: InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Category' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor

I am following a tutorial on how to create a website with razor pages and I want to use all data from my `categories` table to implement custom error checking for my "Edit Category" Page. Though when calling `ToListAsync()` to retrieve my table to loop through it throws this error when `Update()` is subsequently called within `OnPost()` for the category being edited:

```
InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Category' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap<TKey>.ThrowIdentityConflict(InternalEntityEntry entry)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap<TKey>.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry, bool updateDuplicate)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry entry)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, bool acceptChanges, bool modifyProperties)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, bool acceptChanges, bool modifyProperties, Nullable<EntityState> forceStateWhenUnknownKey, Nullable<EntityState> fallbackState)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode<ValueTuple<EntityState, EntityState, bool>> node)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph<TState>(EntityEntryGraphNode<TState> node, Func<EntityEntryGraphNode<TState>, bool> handleNode)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraph(InternalEntityEntry rootEntry, EntityState targetState, EntityState storeGeneratedWithKeySetTargetState, bool forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet<TEntity>.SetEntityState(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState entityState)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet<TEntity>.Update(TEntity entity)
Scratch.Pages.EditCategoryModel.OnPost() in EditCategory.cshtml.cs
+
                _db.Category.Update(Category);
```

Here is my code for context:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Scratch.Model;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Scratch.Pages
{
    [BindProperties]
    public class EditCategoryModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        public Category Category { get; set; }

        public EditCategoryModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Category> categories { get; set; }
        
        

        public async Task OnGet(int Id)
        {
            categories = await _db.Category.ToListAsync();
            //the category to be edited
            Category = _db.Category.Find(Id);
            



        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
        {



            // categories is reset since OnPost() was called, so i need to call it again.
            //but this causes "_db.Category.Update(Category);" to crash the webpage (i assume due to loading the subject category twice?)
            categories = await _db.Category.ToListAsync();
            




            bool duplicate_name = false;
            foreach (Category cat in categories)
            {
                //not counting the name of the subject category
                if (cat.categoryName.Equals(Category.categoryName) && cat.Id != Category.Id)
                {
                    duplicate_name = true;
                    break;
                }
            }



            if (duplicate_name)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Category.categoryName", "categoryName already exists");
            }

            


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //max/min for displayOrder
                if (Category.displayOrder > categories.Count())
                {
                    Category.displayOrder = categories.Count();
                }
                if (Category.displayOrder < 0)
                {
                    Category.displayOrder = 0;
                }
                //i also want to shift all display order indexes down the list if there is not already a vacant index
                int displayOrder = Category.displayOrder;
                bool vacantIndex = true;
                foreach (Category cat in categories)
                {
                    if (cat.displayOrder == displayOrder && cat != Category)
                    {
                        vacantIndex = false; break;
                    }
                }

                if (!vacantIndex)
                {
                    foreach (Category cat in categories)
                    {
                        if (cat.displayOrder <= displayOrder && cat != Category)
                        {
                            cat.displayOrder += 1;
                            _db.Category.Update(cat);

                        }
                    }
                }
                


                _db.Category.Update(Category);
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToPage("/Category Display/Index");
            }
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose I'm asking if I can "untrack" the duplicate `Category` instance or if I can somehow "load" the `categories` table/list without the duplicate instance. Note that I am also potentially updating the rest of the category instances when shifting them down in the `displayOrder`.

---

### Update:

this fixed my issue:

```cs
                //this substitutes:
                //_db.Category.Update(Category);
                //because the tracking of an instance with the same ID as category began when calling _db.Category.ToListAsync()
                foreach (Category cat in categories)
                {
                    if (cat.Id == Category.Id)
                    {
                        
                        cat.displayOrder = displayOrder;
                        cat.categoryName = Category.categoryName;
                        
                        //works without update!
                        //_db.Category.Update(cat);
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have disabled [tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking#no-tracking-queries). Retrieved entities are [being tracked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/#how-to-track-entities), so calling Update is trying to track an entity that is already being tracked. That's why you don't really need to call it. And `SaveChangesAsync` will be enough to persist the update you made in the database.

Comment: Well I do need to call `Update()` for the changes to persist, I just couldn't call it upon `Category` since that would cause the tracking of an id that was already tracked when retrieving `categories`, so I did the above in the above update...

Comment: Wait no you're right, I don't need to call Update(), I can comment it out and it still stores the changes.
my only issue was that my changes were stored within `Category` but not within the instance of the same `Id` within `categories`.